# Where does tab goes?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am working on winform project. At runtime when I am moving through different controls through tab key ; after one button my tab disappears for 2 clicks. I tried all things to fix this. I set `tabstop=false` for all contols in winform but still I am getting same problem.

Then I decided to add following code:

```
Control nextControl = this.GetNextControl(this.guipnlReportPatientMeasurementDetails.Controls[10], true);
```

where GetNextControl property gets the name of the control where my control will go after pressing tab key and `Controls[10]` is the button. So where should I place above piece of code so that I would get the name of next control. Should it be in `button_click` event or somewhere else ?
Guys please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You should set `TabIndex` property for each control according to the Tab order you want to impose (you can set it through designer).

Set `TabStop = false` only for those controls you want to exclude from Tab selection.

There's also a useful button that shows TabIndexes on the form:

[image]

Comment: I have checked in designer ... I have set tabindex as per order needed plus only those controls which are needed on tab click are set to tabstop=false... Can u suggest something about above code??

Comment: @Sachin: Not so clear... why do you need to use GetNextControl ?

Comment: @Sachin: BTW, I'd override `ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)` detecting when `keyData == Keys.Tab`... but, again, I'm not sure about what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: As I already mention that when I am on on some button say button1 and I press tab key the focus doesn't go on next control it disapperars for two tab clicks.

Comment: So I added above code in which guipnlReportPatientMeasurementDetails.Controls[10] is button1 and I am expecting code to give next control it is giving after pressing tab key.

Comment: @Sachin: OK, so it's just to check where the tab focus go...right? well you can set the code wherever you want, personally I'd use form constructor, after IntializeComponents method...

Comment: but it's not working any where I want.... not on buttonclick or on button_GotFocus....

Comment: @Sachin: No idea... GetNextControl is completely independent from the current status of the form (e.g. which control has focus), then wherever you call it, you will get the same result... Just 2 notes: 1) once you reach the last tab element it retuns null; 2) I suspect it ignores TabStop=false property...

Answer (score 1):

You are digging yourself a hole.  Find out what the *real* problem is, there's some kind of control that is either off the window or doesn't properly indicate the focus.  If you have no clue what control that might be then add a timer and a label.  Set the timer's Enabled property to True, Interval to 200.  Write the Tick event like this:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (this.ActiveControl == null) label1.Text = "No control?";
        else label1.Text = this.ActiveControl.Name;
    }
```

*That* tells you where the tab goes.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to fix the tab order on the window before resolving to using this code. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes.. surely taborder are in proper order as I needed.Can u please suggest something about above code??